# after deploying mean website to aws getting errors for post method

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGbey.png)

this error occurs when i deploy my website on aws.on local there was no error comes..
basically i want to add some data and one image to mongoose. in local all works fine.

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
if (!req.files) {
res.status(400).send({ message: "Please select image" });    
}else
{
const file = req.files.image;
 const filename = req.files.image.name;
  const underFile=filename.replace(/\s/g, "");

  const myFileName = underFile.split('.').join('-' + Date.now() + '.');
  file.mv(__dirname + '/uploads/' + myFileName, function (err) {
  if (err) {
  res.status(500).send({
    message:err
  });
  } else {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get("host");
  const tutorial = new Tutorial({
    data: req.body.data,
    image: url + "/uploads/" + myFileName,
    creator : req.userData.userId,
    uploaderName : req.body.name,
    createdDateTime : new Date()        
  });


 //Save post in the database
  tutorial.save(tutorial).then(data => {
    res.status(200).send({
      message:"success"
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:err
    });
  });
  }
  })
  }
  };
```

this is my nodejs save code.i also tried removing all save code and replace only res.status(200).send({ message: "its works " }); to this post request then it works properly. but if i add save code then it does't work

Answer (score 0):

did you remember to update your environment.prod.ts api url in angular for production?

because it will replace enviroment.ts file which is for development.

and also always wrap your functions with try catch block to handle the  error if it happens inside function.

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Please select image' });
    }
    const file = req.files.image;
    const filename = req.files.image.name;
    const underFile = filename.replace(/\s/g, '');

    const myFileName = underFile.split('.').join('-' + Date.now() + '.');
    file.mv(__dirname + '/uploads/' + myFileName, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({
          message: err
        });
      }
      const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
      const tutorial = new Tutorial({
        data: req.body.data,
        image: url + '/uploads/' + myFileName,
        creator: req.userData.userId,
        uploaderName: req.body.name,
        createdDateTime: new Date()
      });

      //Save post in the database
      tutorial
        .save(tutorial)
        .then((data) => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: 'success'
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err
          });
        });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: e });
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes I updated environment.prod.ts..other request successfully get update insert..but for this request gets error..

Comment: try including try catch block and returning error so we can find out more. interestingly there is no statusCode in error

Comment: now it showing                                                                                                     headers: Kd, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", error:
message:
code: "ENOENT"
errno: -2
path: "/var/app/current/app/controllers/uploads/IMG_20190221_094159-1594491367263.jpg"
syscall: "open"                                                                                                                           name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: for more details about that.please check it out my website:-  http://angular-with-node.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ sign up and try to create new post. after creating post please ignore please select image error on design.

Comment: I tried and got the same error. seems ENOENT Error stands for error: No entitiy, and probably coming from file.mv... function. might be the name that you create with split and join or __dirname might wrong.

Comment: @Prakash if I understood well It takes the file in request and moves it to uploads folder which then creates it's url. although it might work finally but doens't seem to be a good way to save files. but why not using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer it's a middleware for handling uploading files which helps a lot and at the end gives the file name on server and you don't need to go though all this. multer s3 also works if you want to save them in AWS S3.